# How to split a column with string values like '[title:item]['title2:item]'...etc into a dictionary with pandas

Tags: python, string, pandas, dictionary, type-conversion

I am trying to clean some data in a dataframe. In particular a column that displays like this:

```
0    [Bean status:Whole][Type of Roast:Medium][Coff...
1    [Type of Roast:Espresso][Coffee Type:Blend]
2    [Bean status:Whole][Type of Roast:Dark][Coffee...
3    [Bean status:Whole][Type of Roast:Light][Coffe...
4                                                  NaN
5    [Roaster:Little City][Type of Roast:Light][Cof...

Name: options, dtype: object
```

My goal is to split this into four columns and assign the corresponding value to the columns to look something like this:

```
     Roaster    Bean Status    Type of Roast    Coffee Type
0    NaN        Whole          Medium           Blend
1    NaN        NaN            Espresso         Blend
..
5    Littl...   Whole          Light            Single Origin
```

I've tried `df.str.split('[', expand=True)` but it is not suitable because the options are not always present or in the same position.

My thoughts were to try to split the strings into a dictionary and store that dictionary in a new dataframe, then join the two dataframes together. However, I'm getting lost trying to store the column into a dictionary. I tried doing this: https://www.fir3net.com/Programming/Python/python-split-a-string-into-a-dictionary.html like so:

```
roasts = {}
roasts = dict(x.split(':') for x in df['options'][0].split('[]'))
print(roasts)
```

and I get this error:

```
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 4; 2 is required
```

I tried investigating what was going on here by storing to a list instead:

```
s = ([x.split(':') for x in df['options'][0].split('[]')])
print(s)

[['[Bean status', 'Whole][Type of Roast', 'Medium][Coffee Type', 'Blend]']]
```

So I see the code is not splitting the string up how I would like, and have played around substituting a single bracket into those various locations without proper results.

Is it possible to get this column into a dictionary or will I have to resort to regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using AmiTavory's sample data

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(options=[
    '[Bean status:Whole][Type of Roast:Medium]', 
    '[Type of Roast:Espresso][Coffee Type:Blend]'
]))
```

### Combination of `re.findall` and `str.split`

```
import re
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame([
    dict(
        x.split(':')
        for x in re.findall('\[(.*?)\]', v)
    )
    for v in df.options
])

  Bean status Coffee Type Type of Roast
0       Whole         NaN        Medium
1         NaN       Blend      Espresso
```

Comment: Very nice! <filler>

Comment: This worked. I had to convert the column to a string (even though it was already showing up as object type). It also took care of a null cell. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You might use

```
df.options.apply(
    lambda s: pd.Series({e.split(':')[0]: e.split(':')[1] for e in s[1: -1].split('][')}))
```

**Example**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(options=[
    '[Bean status:Whole][Type of Roast:Medium]', 
    '[Type of Roast:Espresso][Coffee Type:Blend]'
]))
>>> df.options.apply(
     lambda s: pd.Series({e.split(':')[0]: e.split(':')[1] for e in s[1: -1].split('][')}))
    Bean status Coffee Type Type of Roast
0   Whole   NaN Medium
1   NaN Blend   Espresso
```

**Explanation**

Say you start with a string like

```
s = '[Bean status:Whole][Type of Roast:Medium]'
```

Then

```
s[1: -1]
```

removes the first and last parentheses.

Then,

```
split('][')
```

splits the dividers

Then,

```
e.split(':')[0]: e.split(':')[1]
```

for each of the splits, maps the first part to the second part.

Finally, create a Series from this.

Comment: Thanks this is a great answer, and seems like it should get me what I want. I pulled your example out and used it- worked perfectly. When I use it on my data I get `TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable` not sure why it would be referring to a float though